# sys.stdin.readline() vs input(): is there a difference in the memory required by them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, stdin

I was solving a [question on hackerearth](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/minimum-spanning-tree/practice-problems/algorithm/mr-president/description/).
The question was giving a "Memory Limit Exceeded" error for my solution. When I replaced all the `input()` by `sys.stdin.readline()` the memory limit exceed errors went away. I was wondering why this was happening. Could anyone explain the reason behind this difference?

Edit:
Code for reading input using `stdin.readline()`

```
n, m, k = map(int, stdin.readline().split())

edges = []
mst = []

parent = [i for i in range(n)]
size = [1] * n

for i in range(m):
    x, y, w= map(int, stdin.readline().split())
    edges.append([w, x - 1, y - 1])

edges.sort()
```

Code for reading input using `input()`

```
n, m, k = map(int, input().split())

edges = []
mst = []

parent = [i for i in range(n)]
size = [1] * n

for i in range(m):
    x, y, w= map(int, input().split())
    edges.append([w, x - 1, y - 1])

edges.sort()
```

Comment: Can you post just the portion of your code for reading the input? (The actual algorithms after that should not be relevant if that's actually the problem)

Comment: @tobias_k added.